# The entity type 'Item' cannot be configured as non-owned

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<DToM>().HasKey(t => new { t.DasteBandiId, t.MahsoolId });
    modelBuilder.Entity<Mahsool>(p =>
    {
        p.HasKey(w => w.id);
        p.OwnsOne<Item>(navigationExpression: w => w.Item);
        p.HasOne<Item>(navigationExpression: w => w.Item).WithOne(navigationExpression: w => w.mahsool)
        .HasForeignKey<Item>(w => w.id);
    });
    //تغییر نوع داده قیمت دیتابیس
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>(i =>
    {
        
        i.Property(w => w.price).HasColumnType("تومان");
        i.HasKey(w => w.id);
    });
```

> Error :    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
> The entity type 'Item' cannot be configured as non-owned because it has already been configured as a owned. Use the nested builder in `OwnsOne` or `OwnsMany` on the owner entity type builder to further configure this type.

I used the Ignore call, but the problem is not solved and I cannot create my own tables in the database.

Comment: There's a contradiction. Ether `p.OwnsOne<Item>` or `p.HasOne<Item>`.

Comment: So what do you actually want - owned types or regular relationships?